# how to run linear regression in tensorflow probability, where parameters follow different distributions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-probability

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'y_var':[0,0,0,1,1],
                        'x_c1':[1,2,3,4,5],
                        'x_c2':[6,7,8,9,9],
                        'x_p1':[2,2,2,3,3],
                        'x_p2':[5,6,7,9,9]})
```

How could I run a simple linear regression on `y_var` using `tensorflow_probability` where the weights of `x_c`s follow a `normal` distribution and the weights of `x_p`s follow a `lognormal` distribution ?

**UPDATE**

So for instance if I try this to build the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tf.keras.layers
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfpl = tfp.layers

model = tfk.Sequential([
  tfkl.Dense(1),
  tfpl.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=1)),
  tfpl.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.LogNormal(loc=0, scale=1)),
  tfkl.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])
```

Then this will create 4 layers, where in the end all the parameters will follow a lognormal, whereas I would like only the `x_p`s weights to follow `lognormal`

Comment: The question is too broad, have you gone through the TFP documentation to get started with it? There is a [logistic regression example](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.7/tensorflow_probability/examples/logistic_regression.py) that you may use as a basis.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes I have been through the TFP documentation, I also found [this](https://medium.com/tensorflow/regression-with-probabilistic-layers-in-tensorflow-probability-e46ff5d37baf) , where it adds a single (lambda) layer, but I still do not understand how could I "split/separate" the weights into two distributions

Comment: Just an idea: maybe going via the functional Keras API...

Comment: @desertnaut Does keras also have PPL feature ?

Comment: If you man TFP layers, yes: https://towardsdatascience.com/bayesian-neural-networks-in-10-mins-in-tfp-c735ec99384f

Comment: @desertnaut I still cannot see how to specify specific distributions for each parameter separately. I was more looking for something like `pyro` functionality like [this](https://pyro.ai/examples/bayesian_regression_ii.html), where the model is very clearly defined here ```mean = a + b_a * is_cont_africa + b_r * ruggedness + b_ar * is_cont_africa * ruggedness``` and each parameter has a different distribution which is defined explicitly. But I am not sure if it is possible to do so in `tensorflow probability`

Comment: Sorry, have not further experience with this stuff myself, so I cannot really help here...

Comment: @desertnaut No worries. Thanks for your effort in any case